# HTML EMAIL from PHP not parsing correctly

Tags: html, email, html-email, php

I am working on a splash page which contains a form. When the form is Submitted my add.php writes the form input fields to a SQL server, then it is supposed to send an html email to the person who filled out the form.

**Issue #1**: The email is received, but it displays the html markup; not the formatted version of the email.
[image]
**Issue #2**: The "From" field is being populated with "text/html" and displays the webserver: tribeca.websitewelcome.com. It is not showing the specified email.

Here is the contents of add.php

```
<?php 

$name=$_POST['Name']; 
$email=$_POST['Email'];

$to = $_POST['Email']; 
$subject = 'Company Name Webinar Contact';
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Email</title>
</head>
<body  style="background-color: #e9e9e9;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr> <td style="width:600px;"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600px" border="0"    style="background-color: #fff;margin:0 auto;border:solid 10px #fff;font-family: lucida grande, sans-serif;">
<tr> <td style="height:100px;"> <center> <img src="eq-logo.jpg" /> </center> </td> </tr>
<tr style="height:1px; background-color:#dcdcdc"> <td > </td> </tr>
<tr style="height:1px; background-color:#f1f5ee"> <td > </td> </tr>
<tr style="height:100px;"> <td > <h1 style="color:#e10621;">Thank you for your enquiry&#33;</h1> <h3>Someone from our team will contact you shortly&#46;</h3> <p style="line-height:28px;">We&#39;ve helped hundreds achieve their financial dreams and look forward to showing YOU how to turn YOUR common &#34;cents&#34; into dollars&#46; Please take a few moments to check out the other areas of our <a href="http://equanimityconcepts.com.au/">website</a>&#46; </p> <p><b>The Company Name Team</b></p> </td> </tr>
</table> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> <center> <img src="bottom-shadow.png" /> </center> </td> </tr>
</table>
</body> </html>
';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: <donotreply@companyname.com.au>' . "\r\n";

// Connect 
mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "user_password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

// Write 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES ('$name', '$email')") ; 

// Email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

header('Location: http://companyname.com.au');

exit();

?>
```

Additional Notes:
I have tried separating the 'message' out into line by line html as in chris coyiers html email tut with no luck. Here you see the html in its entirety in the message area.

Comment: Try using all double-quotes `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n"; $headers .= "From: <donotreply@companyname.com.au>" . "\r\n";`

Comment: Thank you Fred! you were correct as well. \r\n must be contained in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your quotes! Use double quotes for your \r\n lines:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <donotreply@companyname.com.au>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Just click on the white checkmark (next to the answer) till it turns green to accept and close the question. @Jared.DAGI Plus that's `"\r\n"` and not `"/r/n"` which will definitely give you trouble if you use `/`

Comment: Yes, "\r\n" sorry to confuse anyone with the same issue!